How to addForce to a GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() of another script
I'm trying to make a similar to Fruit ninja game. But when I was making the script of the fruits spawning and then moving across the screen I ran into trouble.
public class PeaScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D peaRB;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        peaRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void MovePea()
    {
       peaRB.AddForce(Vector2.right * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}


public class Fruit_Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject FruitOne;
    public GameObject FruitTwo;
    public GameObject FruitThree;
    public GameObject FruitFour;
    bool one = false;
    bool two = false;
    bool three = false;
    bool four = false;
    float oneF = 0f;
    float twoF = 0f;
    float threeF = 0f;
    float fourF = 0f;
    public int RoundCount = 0;
    private PeaScript PeaScript;
    public Rigidbody2D pea;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        NewRound();
        FruitOne = GameObject.Find("Pea_vegtable(1)");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void NewRound()
    {
        oneF = Random.Range(0,2);
        twoF = Random.Range(0, 2);
        threeF = Random.Range(0, 2);
        fourF = Random.Range(0, 2);
        Debug.Log(oneF);
        if (RoundCount !=5 && oneF==1)
        {
            PeaScript = FindObjectOfType<PeaScript>();
            PeaScript.peaRB = pea;
            transform.position = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
            pea.AddForce(Vector2.right * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        }
    }
}


I tried to only make a function in pea script to run that would push it but that did not work as it would not let me call it.

I'm a bit new to Unity myself, but I wonder if it has to do with not initializing pea. You create a RigidBody2D named pea, and later assign PeaScript.peaRB = pea, but pea is never initialized.

Your error is in the newRound() function:
PeaScript.peaRB = pea;

sets the Rigidbody in the PeaScript to the unassigned value of pea.
Reverse it to:
pea = PeaScript.peaRB;

I would also recommend calling GetComponent(); in an Awake() instead of in Start() to make sure it's initialized before it is used.

why you are using hard way? make public variable as PeaScript and add your script ( in this case you need to add that game object have this script ) to your game object from components in right side and then you can access your script or you can use
GameObject peaObject = GameObject.Find("YOUR_PEA_OBJECT_NAME");
PeaScript script = peaObject.GetComponent<PeaScript>();



Just Tried doing what you suggested but got a null reference exception even though I assigned the pea Object to the correct Game Object
